# I am a Italian and Australian citizein living and working in the UK. How will I be affected by brexit

Tags: dual-citizenship, australian-citizens, brexit, italian-citizens

I am a dual citizen of Australia and Italy. I am currently living and working in the Uk on my Italian citizenship. How will Brexit affect me and what do I need to do.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://www.gov.uk/staying-uk-eu-citizen?

Comment: Register for the "settled status" scheme, and Brexit shouldn't affect you much at all.